Conditionaly use Environment Variables depending on Branch Name
I have two different environments.

dev
prod

In the codemagic.yaml I want to use the same environment variable key, e.g., $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID. Depending on the branch triggering the build, I want the respective variable value.
According to the official documentation I can use the variable groups. This means that for the same variable name I can set a different value as long as the variables belong to different groups.
From the built-in environment variables, I can utilize the CM_BRANCH to check which branch triggered the pipeline.
How can I set to choose which environment variable value should be used according to the branch? I couldn't find anything around this.

here is some ideas how you can handle such configuration
Option 1 (works better with simple pipelines)

you define 2 environment variables $PROD_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID and $DEV_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
in codemagic.yaml you can use something like this

if [ "$CM_BRANCH" == "main" ]; then 
  export FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$PROD_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
else  
  export FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$DEV_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
fi

# replace with your command
gcloud --quiet config set project $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID

...

Option 2 (for bigger projects)

create prod and dev environment groups with $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID variable name
in codemagic.yaml you can use YAML aliases to define your commands

definitions:
  scripts:
    - &my_script
      name: Use $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
      scripts: gcloud --quiet config set project $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID

...


now you can add workflows for each branch/environment. For instance:

workflows:
  prod:
    triggering:
      events:
        - pull_request
        - push
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: main
    scripts:
      - *my_script
    environment:
      group:
        - prod


for dev workflow you need to use dev group and also you can add/modify script steps if needed

I hope it helps.

I think I will go for option 1. Option 2 seems to be an overkill since I will be duplicating everything in the workflow but the variable. Thank you!
